# How is the prototype constructed such that function context doesn't refer to the `prototype` object

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects, prototypal-inheritance

For example:

```
function Car () {
    this.x = 0;
}

Car.prototype.go = function () {
    this.x += 20;
}

var car = new Car();
car.go(); // adds 20 to car.x, not car.prototype.x??
```

Does this have to do with the new keyword? How exactly does the new keyword interact with the prototype?? The prototype exists before I called the new keyword, so I'm curious how the new keyword grabs the context and applies it to prototype's functions

Comment: It "copies" it to the new object.

Comment: no it doesn't though, because there would be no point in having prototypal shared functions if they were copied

Comment: There would be: references are "copied". `var a = {}; var b = a;` here are the 2 "copies" of the same reference that refer to the same object.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Inheritance_and_the_prototype_chain

Answer (score 2):

This is nothing to do with prototypes; it's just how function calls work.  If you call a function as `one.two.three`, `this` becomes `one.two`.

```
var foo = { a: function() { this.b = 20; } };
foo.a();
console.log(foo);
```

It doesn't matter where/how the function was defined, only how it was called.  (Try calling `Car.prototype.go()` directly and see what happens.)

See also: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this

Comment: hmm, interesting. I tried setting window.x = 0, then calling Car.prototype.go() but it didn't work, didn't change window.x

Comment: i guess because of what you're saying, it would try Car.prototype.x += 20

Comment: tried same thing with `Car.prototype.x = 0` then `Car.prototype.go()` and `Car.prototype.x` became `NaN`

Comment: i just tried that and it worked fine for me; `Car.prototype.x` became 20

Comment: sorry not sure what was going on, looks like Car.prototype.go works